# Set profile fields with values during login with Profile:Edit

Tags: profile-edit

I was wondering if it's possible to update some profile fields during login using Profile:Edit?

The reason is, I have a survey where people can login at the end of it to save their result. But I'd like to just pass some hidden fields with the values, but i'm not sure if it's possible to effectively save an edit to a profile during login? :/

Comment: Pretty sure it's not possible out-of-the-box, but it would make for a pretty quick and easy custom extension. P:E provides some custom hooks you can use: http://mightybigrobot.com/docs/profile-edit/#extension-hooks

Comment: What about using javascript to pass survey items as a variable to populate hidden profile fields?